# Calling imported module functions directly in elixir

Tags: import, elixir

I have just started learning Elixir and I am unable to figure out how import works in Elixir.
When I import a module into another module using `import` I am unable to call the imported function by using the module in which it is imported.

But I am able to call function of imported module inside function in the module which it was imported.

```
defmodule A do
  def func do
   IO.puts("func called")
  end
end

defmodule B do
  import A
end

A.func # o/p: "func called"
B.func # (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: B.func/0

defmodule B do
  import A

  def func2 do
    func
  end
end

B.func2 # o/p "func called"
```

I am unable to figure out why B.func not works while I was able to call `func` from `func2`. Is there some kind of theory that I am missing. Coming from the Ruby background this behaviour looks odd to me. Please can anybody help me out or point me to some good resource to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`import` does not really import anything in the way many other languages do. All it does is makes the imported module's exported functions accessible from the current namespace. To quote [the docs](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#import)

> We use `import` whenever we want to easily access functions or macros from other modules without using the fully-qualified name.

If you want `A.func` and `B.func` to point to the same function you have a couple options. The first is simple - make a wrapper function:

```
defmodule B do
  def func do
     A.func
  end
end
```

If you want some more complex inheritance type stuff you can look into creating a [`__using__`](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#use) macro with [`defoverridable`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/Kernel.html#defoverridable/1) and [`super`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#super/1)

Comment: Thanks for the links and detailed answer

Comment: Another way to put it is that import is lexical, this article can hopefully clarify it: http://thepugautomatic.com/2015/11/elixir-scoping/ Also, avoid the "inheritance like" stuff, it is encouraged only for callbacks. :)